# Alamofire get method with parameters in the url with header swift

Tags: swift, parameters, get, alamofire

I have a get method with 3 parameters on the base url itself.I have tried the following code, but it is going to failure condition saying either not a valid url or not a valid JSON.
What is the correct way to approach this?
The code i have used is as below:

```
 let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","x-token":self.token!]
        
        
        let todosEndpoint: String = "https://reachwebdemo.com/2020/10/listcribdev/api/chatnotification?" + "channel_sid=\(self.channelsid!)&author=\(self.userid!)&message=\(inputMessage)"
        if let encoded = todosEndpoint.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed),let url = URL(string: encoded)
         {
            print("notify url is",url)
            AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseString { response in
                
                switch response.result {
                                  case .success(let json):
                                      print("Validation Successful for push notification",json)
                                
                case let .failure(error):
                    print("error for push notificaton",error.errorDescription)
                           
            }
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Test which one is invalid. Instead of not knowing which one if failing, do it in two times: if `let encoded = ... { if let url = ... { } else { print("url is invalid") } } else { print("encoded is nil") }`

Comment: okay i will check this

Comment: BUT, Alamofire should do all that for you. You need to give parameters: `["channel_sid": self.channelsid, "author": self.userid, "message: inputMessage]`. instead of constructing yourself the url. See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#get-request-with-url-encoded-parameters

Comment: but this is get method and not post method

Comment: Scroll a little before. The anchor link is mess-up.

Comment: Sorry i didn't  understand what you are saying

Comment: On the linked page, look for "GET Request With URL-Encoded Parameters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You user parameters like url and it's wrong way to make request like this.
You need add parameters on request method like parameters. And yes, you can use parameters on 'GET' requests.

```
    let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","x-token":self.token!]
    let todosEndpoint: String = "https://reachwebdemo.com/2020/10/listcribdev/api/chatnotification"
    let params:[String: Any] = ["channel_sid":self.channelsid!, "author":self.userid!, "message": inputMessage]
    
    if let encoded = todosEndpoint.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed),
       let url = URL(string: encoded) {
               print("notify url is",url)
               AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseString { response in
                   switch response.result {
                   case .success(let json):
                       print("Validation Successful for push notification",json)
                   case let .failure(error):
                       print("error for push notificaton",error.errorDescription)
                              
                   }
               }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.both were helpful